# Is this possible to embed a SWF and access it without giving any movie clips instance names?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a folder full of SWF files. Each SWF is its own animation. I have several people submitting their animations for this project. I would like to embed all these SWF's into my project and use `.play()` `.stop()` and other movieclip related commands on them as a whole.

By this I mean, the artist sends me the SWF, my AS3 script embeds it, then I can access it with say `animation_1.stop();` without the artist ever having to enter a instance name, or export for ActionScript name.

I plan to create a shell script which will take all the swf's in a folder and create a AS3 file with all the embed statements. The instance name that will be given to each one by the shell script will be the file name.

Is this possible to embed a SWF and access it without giving any movie clips instance names or exporting for Actionscript?

**UPDATE:**

@annonymously answer below helped a lot. Here are some other resources that helped me:

Great Resource - http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/externalclips/ext_clip2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you actually want then you can try using `getChildAt(index)`.

Here is a tutorial for this:

http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1435

Comment: Not sure how getChildAt() will help but the article sounded exactly like what I needed... and they used it so, i'll give it a go and report back what happens :) Thanks!

Comment: getChildAt allows you to access any child of the swf without its instance name

Comment: If my answer helped, you should accept it, otherwise explain the problem differently or answer your own question

Comment: I had a chance to mess around with this today. Your answer was a big help. Thanks.